# What's the name of this small square tree fence at the base of the tree?

Tags: identification, trees

Sorry, this question might seem not so bright but I don't know how to search for such thing in order to find more using Google.

The purpose is obvious - to protect the plants at the base of the tree but I have no idea how to call it.

Maybe the people working in the urbanization also have some sort of technical name for this, instead of calling it "small cute square tree fence at the base of the tree".

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Tree pit fence' or 'tree box fence' or 'tree pit guard' are the right expressions.

See, for example, the following web pages:

http://www.greenblue.com/na/type/tree-pit-fences/

http://suburbanweldingcompany.com/treeboxfences1.htm

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they've got a particular name - they're just wooden frames or framework of various designs, heights and widths to enclose a bed, particularly a small bed. In a garden, they might be used for pure decoration, but in public places, its just to stop people and animals walking over them, deliberately or inadvertently. It's not to protect the tree - the fact there's a tree in the middle is neither here nor there, is quite coincidental, any protection fencing round a tree is usually metalwork, the short fencing as shown is there to protect the flowering plants. And to use some English vernacular, they're also there to tart up the area a bit.

I'm quite curious as to where this town or city is...

Comment: It's in [Barcelona](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Barcelona_tree_pit_fence_2017_A.jpg/693px-Barcelona_tree_pit_fence_2017_A.jpg).

Comment: @Fructibus ah, cool, I see - is that where all the other pictures you've posted re street furniture/planting recently were taken? If so, I might just have to come and have a look while I'm still European!

Comment: Yes, there are many interesting features on the streets here. Quite a nice city. We can meet here if you wish so.

Comment: I'll certainly let you know if/when I do make it there -  be nice to do it in spring I think

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply to your message. Maybe the easiest way to contact me is to leave a message (or send mail) using my Wikipedia user page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Fructibus